# Apply js function to all inputs within a panel on an aspx form

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# WebForms application where I add an onkeydown event to all of the textboxes within a panel in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var txt in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            txt.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "capsLock(event);");
        }
    }
```

The above works as expected.  All of the textboxes within panel1 have onkeydown.  Here's an example:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtFrom" type="text" id="MainContent_txtFrom" class="form-control" onkeydown="capsLock(event);">
```

Here is the capsLock function I copied from w3:

```
function capsLock() {
            var input = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtFrom");             
            var text = document.getElementById("capslockdiv");
            input.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
                    text.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    text.style.display = "none"
                }
            })
        };
```

The above works just as expected for MainContent_txtFrom.  However, instead of adding each control to the function, I would prefer to apply it to all input elements.  I attempted changing var input to use getElementsByTagName("input"), but of course that didn't work.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you already have an event attached to each input from the code in Page_Load. You should change your function capsLock to take in the event parameter as it is being set currently, then there is no need to find the element and add the event again.

```
 function capsLock(event) {
  var text = document.getElementById("capslockdiv");
  if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```